# Cypress test if input field value has multiple lines

Tags: javascript, cypress, textarea

I want to check with a cypress test if the value is correct in a single-line text fields and multi-line text area.

I here have a single line box where I use the code down below to add an input:

> `cy.followLabel("When did the incident happen?").type("single \nline");`

Same thing for the multi line text area

> `cy.followLabel("Deenter code herescribe what happened").type("multiple \nlines");`

[image]

I tried to validate it with .should() but haven't found any chainers that would suit my need.

Is there something like `.contains("\n")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly check that the innerText has the new line character `\n`.

```js
cy.get('selector').then(($ele) => {
  expect($ele).to.contain('\n')
})
```

In case your inner text doesn't have the newline characters, you assert the style tag containing `overflow-wrap: break-word`

```js
cy.get('selector').should('have.attr', 'style').and('include', 'overflow-wrap: break-word')
```

Comment: This still gives me an error: `expected '<textarea#id2196071612292268033.big.valid>' to contain '\n'`. I believe it searches for the string "\n" and therefore throws the error

Comment: can you extract the inner text and tell me what you get or you can also post the html with the multi line value present.

Comment: In the single field I get: "single line".
In the multi line I get: "multiple 
lines"

Comment: can you post your html with the required text added in the multi line text area?

Comment: `<textarea id="id4549233646300561409" name="field_102" class="big valid" required="" maxlength="20000" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 179.989px;" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>`

Comment: I cannot see the text `Deenter code herescribe what happened` ?

Comment: `<div class="formElementContainer"><label for="id4998773089895448577">Describe what happened*</label><textarea id="id4998773089895448577" name="field_102" class="big valid" required="" maxlength="20000" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 179.989px;" aria-invalid="false"></textarea><label id="id4998773089895448577-error" class="error" for="id4998773089895448577" style="display: none;"></label></div>` Sorry for the crappy formatting

Comment: Thanks for the HTML. So since I cannot see any text, I am assuming the text is not reflected as inner text in the text area filed. So the next option would be to compare the `Style` attribute for both single line text area and multi line text area. The component that is extra or different in Multi line, then you can assert. My assumption is that for multiline the style tag will have `overflow-wrap: break-word`, so I have updated the answer with this.

Answer (score 4):

Chai Assertion Library has a `singleLine` assertion in the [chai-string](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-string/) module.

> **singleLine**
> assert.singleLine('abcdef');
> expect('abcdef').to.be.singleLine();

To use assertions from other libraries, see Cypress recipe [Adding Chai Assertions](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/extending-cypress__chai-assertions)

**Simple example**

Install

```js
yarn add -D chai-string

//or

npm install -D chai-string
```

Test

```js
chai.use(require('chai-string'));

it('tests for singleLine', () => {

  cy.get('input')
    .type("single \nline")
    .invoke('val')
    .should('be.singleLine')  // passes

  cy.get('textarea')
    .type("multiple \nlines")
    .invoke('val')
    .should('not.be.singleLine')  // passes
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know there is an assertion "match" for regex.

```
match(RegExp)
Aliases: matches    
expect('testing').to.match(/^test/)
```

(from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions)

So in your case the regex could be `match(/.*\n.*/gm)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution. Just add should with the chainer "have.value" to your DOM element and then you are able to check for new lines.

```
.should('have.value','multiple\nlines');
```